# Use an object as the up target on a track to constraint

Tags: constraints

Is it possible to use another object as the up axis on a track to constraint?
By default I only seem to be able to use the world X, Y or Z axis.

At the moment I'm using a single bone IK constrain and setting up a pole vector.
Is there a way to do this with normal object constraints?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question right. A "Locked Track" constraint can achieve this: [image: 1]
The order of these constraints matter, if these two are switched it'll go wonky.

Comment: Not really. I have a object that I want to point at another object. Theres no need to move the contrained object I just want to drive it's rotation. A track to constraint is perfect for this but doesn't seem to allow you to use a third object as an up vector